# Why aren't values implicitly convertible to string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, compiler-construction, implicit-conversion

I have some code like:

```
int value = 5;
MessageBox.Show ( value );
```

and the `MessageBox.Show` complains saying:

> "cannot convert from 'int' to
>   'string'"

I seem to remember some cases where values seem to be implicitly converted to string values, but can't recall them exactly.

What's the reason behind this decision that any value isn't implicitly convertible to string values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751303/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-x-to-string-when-and-how-it-decides-that-it

Comment: Is this question about missing implicit conversion, or about calling the Messagebox.Show with an integer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show()` only accepts a string.  When you use something like `Debug.WriteLine`, it accepts a bunch of different object types, including `object`, and then calls `ToString()` on that object.  This is probably what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 12):

A short solution (everywhere you need a string):

```
 MessageBox.Show(""+value);
```

But I would prefer a `ToString()` or a `String.Format()` in most cases.

To answer the "Why" part: because implicit conversions can be dangerous and can undermine type-safety.
 `"1" + 2 = "12" = 12`, not always what you want or expect.

Comment: Good point Henk, I didn't know the cons of implicit conversions.

Comment: @Joan: If you're familiar with the way javascript handles strings (or at least seen it enough), you will appreciate that most languages don't do as much implicit conversions.  :)  Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1995298#1995298) and all the other javascript related answers.

Answer (score 3):

For the exact reason, you would have to ask either the C# compiler guys, or one of the .NET runtime guys.

However, there are no places in the .NET framework or the C# language where values are automatically and implicitly convertible to strings.

You might, however, think of the way string concatenation works, but that only works because there are a lot of overloads on the `string.Concat` method, including one that takes an object.

In other words, this is allowed:

```
string s = "Hello there: " + 4;
```

Other methods around in the framework also has lots of overloads, such as Debug.WriteLine and such, where it will easily accept your integer or decimal, convert it to a string through a call to .ToString, and then print it.

It isn't, however, something built into string or int, but the method itself.

Comment: Hi downvoter, please leave a comment as to what is wrong, so that I have a chance to correct it, and learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
```