# After click on button how to retrieve dynamically textboxes value which is created in panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

**After creating a dynamic textboxes. once fill the value into textboxes. I am unable to retrieve the entered value from code behind. Please can you please help us. **

//Aspx controler//

```
<asp:panel id="pnlTextBoxes" runat="server" cssclass="Paneldetails">
```

//C# code//

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = results.data[i].name.ToString();
txt.CssClass = "tooltips";
txt.MaxLength = Convert.ToInt32(results.data[i].maxLength);
pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(txt);
```

///tried code to retrieve the textboxes values///

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in pnlTextBoxes.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            DSF.name = ((TextBox)ctrl).ID;
            DSF.value = ((TextBox)ctrl).Text;
            summ.Add(DSF);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19637033/1068246

Comment: what exactly is your problem here? is `summ` empty after the loop? how many textboxes did you add to `pnlTextBoxes.Controls` and how many did you get out?

Comment: As per the data, dynamically textboxes will be create so it's not a stable ,and while debugging  i m not getting any textboxes.  foreach (Control ctrl in pnlTextBoxes.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox) it's showing null.

Comment: does the creation of textboxes happen in a loop? because you code creates only 1 textbox and adds it to `Controls`.

Comment: Yes.it is inside of loop. I forgot to mentioned loop part.

Comment: can you try `pnlTextBoxes.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`